# Can chloralkali process be used with ocean water to produce sodium hydroxide?

Tags: electrolysis

Are there any modern-day Chloralkali plants that create $\ce{NaOH}$ using water from the ocean?

I'm trying to understand how modern-day plants that use the [Chloralkali process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloralkali_process) to create $\ce{NaOH}$ (also chlorine, hydrogen, and $\ce{NaCl}$) obtained from brine solution.

Specifically, I was thinking of the increasing creation of desalinization plants. Are there any plants that intake the waste water from desalinization plants to produce Sodium Hydroxide ($\ce{NaOH}$)?

Comment: Intentional usage of dirty input ( not only NaCl ) would lead to dirty product. [Seawater#Chemical_composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawater#Chemical_composition)